# Nifi : write to flowfile

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I am trying to write to the flowfile in Nifi using groovy with the 
outputStream ( which is a bytearrayoutputstream).   However, the size that i write to the flowfile is zero.  Am i doing it wrong ? thanks in advance.

code:
FlowFile newFlowFile = sess.create();

```
newFlowFile = sess.write(newFlowFile, { out ->
    outputStream
} as OutputStreamCallback)
```

Comment: what are contents that you try to write into flowfile? What issue you have faced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the `outputStream` is an bytearrayoutputstream then you can use [ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(stream)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#writeTo(java.io.OutputStream)) method to write content of your bytearray to other output stream.

```
newFlowFile = sess.write(newFlowFile, { out ->
    outputStream.writeTo(out)
} as OutputStreamCallback)
```

Comment: What is I have to write `java.io.File` to `FlowFile`? Is there any utility class for this? I found there are some utility classes in nifi like [StreamUtil](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-commons/nifi-utils/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/stream/io/StreamUtils.java). But I guess I cant use it for this. Currently I am doing it as follows: `session.write(currentEntityFlowFile, outputStream -> { outputStream.write(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file)); });`. Is this correct? Is there any better way?

Comment: you could use [Session.importFrom](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.nifi/nifi-api/1.0.0/org/apache/nifi/processor/ProcessSession.html#importFrom-java.nio.file.Path-boolean-org.apache.nifi.flowfile.FlowFile-) : `flowfile = session.inportFrom( file.toPath(), flowfile);`